# Embedding External Dashboard within an iFrame

Tags: visualforce, dashboard, iframe

I have a requirement to embed a margin minder dashboard (this is a third party dashboard similar to tableau) onto the Account page. I have started building this using an iframe in a Visualforce page. I am able to display the dashboard on the page with no problem.

My issue comes when I try to filter that dashboard based on the record that is displayed. I am matching up (at least I think) my filter perimeters with what is listed in the table of the dashboard (I doing this by account id). However when I load a record, the dashboard returns/displays all results instead of just those that pertains to the record which is loaded.  Below is my code. I have also renamed the Account object "Branch." Any suggestions would be appreciated:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:iframe src="https://analytics.xxxxx.com/SDM/SDM.aspx?ds=MM_Web&view=viewer&categoryId=0&dashboard=Branches&:hideTopBar=true&:filters=Wholesaler.SalesForce_BranchID&:embed=y&:showShareOptions=false&:toolbar=false&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no&Id%20(Account)={! Account.Id }" height="300px" width="100%" scrolling="true">
  </apex:iframe>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution or fix for this was to insert the following function into the url (Account)={!Account.Id}. After inserting this right after the dashboard description, when the iframe loads the dashboard is automatically filtered according to the Salesforce record that is loaded.